# jquery with nested gridview in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I know there are many solution of my problem. But i want to do some different in my code.
What i want to do is that, when i click on plus sign then that row should be hide. and correspond child table will be visible. this works for me. Now problem is that when collaps my child row, then correspond row should be visible.
Here is my jquery for nested gridview(Nested Gridview worksfine)

```
  $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {


        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td><img src='../Images/gvminus.png'> </img></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
        //$(this).attr("src", "../Images/gvminus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").andSelf().css('display', 'none');

    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {

        $(this).closest("tr").andSelf().remove();
        $(this).closest("tr").prev().css('display','');
    });
```

and Here Parent and child grids are as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"
        OnRowDataBound="gvParent_OnRowDataBound" Width="100%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../Images/gvplus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlChild" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Double"
                            BorderColor="#df5015" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Child" HeaderText="ChildValue" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Catagory" HeaderText="Catagory" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Instead of using closest add an id for each row. Then use it to find the correct row

Comment: Sam i have updated my code with gridview. so can you tell me how can i set id to each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "/Content/img/minus.gif");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "/Content/img/plus.gif");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

```
...
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="templateField-Plus">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="/Content/img/plus.gif" />

...
```

a real example is [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

It works well for me, hope it will be the same for you)

Answer (score 0):

```
function GridViewDesign() {
    var i = 0
    $(".Test").each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].innerHTML.indexOf("Hide") != -1) {
            $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $('#cphContent_gvSchMaint_pnlSchedule_' + i)[0].innerHTML + "</td></tr>");
            $('#cphContent_gvSchMaint_pnlSchedule_' + i)[0].innerHTML = "";
        }
        i = i + 1;
    });
}


<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="ShowHide">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="topdarkcommon dark drow" id="flex">
            <div class="whitetext">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShowHide" runat="server" CommandName="Show" CssClass="Test"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="50px" Height="42px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="UpcomingPanel">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSchedule" runat="server" Style="position: relative">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvUpCommingSchedule" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="ChildGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                BorderColor="Black">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UpComingDate" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource1">
                        <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SchTask" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource2">
                        <ItemStyle Width="55%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ResponsiblePersonName" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource3">
                        <ItemStyle Width="25%" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle CssClass="testClass" />
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="testClass" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```